# What options for most convenient usage of a numeric wrapper class in numeric expressions?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Suppose I have a wrapper class for a numerical value with some "extra functions":

```
struct DblWrapper{
  double value;
  void func1(); // maybe to print nicely
  void func2(); // maybe to register this for automatic capture at data source
}
```

Now, I'd also like to use instances of this wrapper as convenient as possible in numerical expressions, something like:

```
DblWrapper a;
DblWrapper b;
DblWrapper d;
double c = a * b; // Best idea: overload operator () ( c = a() * b() )
d = c; // Best idea: overload operator =
```

Or would there actually be a way for fully-automatic conversion to the numerical value as given in the `c = a * b` example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write conversion operator and conversion constructor.

```
operator double() const
{
   return value;
}

DblWrapper(double d) : value(d)
{
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d898b3f724ad619)